# Smaller font size of the algorithm description?

Tags: algorithms, fontsize

`\small` or other tag seems can not change the font size of the line number.

The package I use is `\usepackage{algorithmic}`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to tex.SX. So that people can better understand your question, it's helpful to add a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. What package are you loading to display the algorithms?

Comment: I agree with Alan, there are several different packages that can be used to describe an algorithm, without knowing which one you are using, there really isn't much anybody can do to help you.

Comment: @ Alan I use the \usepackage{algorithmic}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\algsetup{linenosize=\small}`. See p. 12 of the documentation of the algorithms bundle for details.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\algsetup{linenosize=\small}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\IF{some condition is true}
\STATE do some processing
\ELSE
\STATE do the default actions
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it only changes the size of the number of line but not the global font, how can i change the font size???

Comment: @gpu_drug: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\small}
`

Comment: This did't work for me. The solution from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16059/vertical-spacing-in-the-algorithm-environment works.

Comment: @lockstep can we apply `\usepackage{etoolbox}\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\small}` only for a specific algorithm instead of applying it globally?