# Reduce vertical spacing in the algorithm environment

Tags: line-spacing, algorithms

I'm using the algorithm/algorithmic packages and want to condense some of the vertical space between an algorithm's line numbers in order to save space. Ideally, I would like to remove 1 to 2mm of space between each line. Is there a way to do this with the algorithm package without editing the .sty file?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do this either by using the `spacing` environment from the [setspace](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package or by using the second argument of the `\fontsize` command to change the value of `\baselineskip`; an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

{\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont
\begin{algorithmic}
\IF{$n$ is odd}
\RETURN \TRUE
\ELSE
\RETURN \FALSE
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
}

\begin{spacing}{0.8}
\begin{algorithmic}
\IF{$n$ is odd}
\RETURN \TRUE
\ELSE
\RETURN \FALSE
\ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Couldn't get the spacing command to work (neither outside or inside of the enclosing \begin{algorithm} and \end{algorithm} tags), but the \fontsize command worked perfectly - thanks Gonzalo!

Comment: I used the spacing environment for a start and worked nicely. If the text gets too cluttered then use the fontsize command, as well.

Comment: @g24l: Since your answer is supporting the very similar ealier solution give by Gonzalo, I converted it to a comment to this answer.

Comment: @ralphey This seems to work for `algorithm`:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348922/30201