# How to remove/change the vertical spacing before and after an 'algorithm' environment?

Tags: spacing, floats, algorithms

I saw a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16059/vertical-spacing-in-the-algorithm-environment) that tells me how to change the spacing *in* an algorithm environment, but I don't know how to do remove/change the space before and after an algorithm environment like:

```
% remove the space here
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
[...]
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
% remove the space here
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I solved it in an "ugly" way by adding a

```
\vspace*{-.4cm}
```

at the respective places. For my case, this is fine, since I only have one algorithm environment in my tex file, however if you want it automatically be done in all your algorithm environments, there should be another way.

Answer (score 18):

LaTeX has three length variables to control (i) the distance between two adjacent floating objects (such as figure, table, or algorithm objects), (ii) the distance between a float at the top (bottom) of a page and the text below (above) it, and (iii) the distance between an in-text float and the text above and below it; they are called `\floatsep`, `\textfloatsep`, and `\intextsep`, respectively. (LaTeX also has three more such variables to control the spacing above and/or below floats on floats-only pages; these are `\@fptop`, `\@fpbot`, and `\@fpsep`, respectively.)

To completely suppress the in-text separation of a float (not recommended, by the way!!), you'd type (in the preamble)

```
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
```

i.e., you'd set `\intextsep` to a fixed length of 0 points. A better solution, if you're pressed for space (pun intended), would be to set

```
\setlength{\intextsep}{1\baselineskip}
```

Here's a MWE that uses the algorithm2e package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\newcommand{\lipsone}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, 
adipiscing vitae, felis.}
\newcommand{\lipstwo}{Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque 
habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac 
turpis egestas.}
\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{With default setting of \texttt{\textbackslash intextsep}} 
\lipsone

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{A random example}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{Some input}[h]
\KwResult{Some output}
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{read}
{go back to beginning\;}
\end{algorithm}

\lipstwo


\subsubsection*{After setting \texttt{\textbackslash intextsep} to 0pt}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt} 
\lipsone

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Another random example}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{Some input}
\KwResult{Some output}
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{read}
{go back to beginning\;}
\end{algorithm}

\lipstwo

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not allowed to comment as I don't have enough reputation points. To solve these issues, just add

```
\setlength{\AlCapSkip}{1em}
```

To the preamble and the caption to all Algorithm figures will move down without affecting other captions.

Comment: Also, you can change 1em to other amounts in case you want a bigger or smaller gap

Comment: No. What you're suggesting is specific to [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e); this is different from the interface supplied by the [`algorithms` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) (which provides `algorithm` and `algorithmic`). It is also different from what is provided by [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx).

Comment: ...moreover, the request in this question is for spacing between the `algorithm` float and the surrounding text, not within the environment between the algorithm and the `\caption`.

Comment: Ah, cool, thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{figure}[tb]
```

or

```
\begin{algorithm}[tb]
```

or

```
\begin{table}[tb]
```

This `[tb]` parameter works like charm with almost anything.

Comment: Are you sure this answers the question? The ``[tb]`` parameter changes the placement of the float, but not directly the vertical spacing around it.