# vertical space after algorithm

Tags: spacing, algorithms

I am using the usual `algorithm` package for a paper. However, LaTeX puts too much vspace below algorithms. I have already reduced `\floatsep`, `\textfloatsep` and `\intextsep` but it does not seem to help. For figures, I can use negative `\vspaces` after the figure to get less space after it. However, this does not work for algorithms as there is a line displayed below the algorithm. If I use a negative vspace in the algorithm environment, the line gets pulled into the pseudocode.

Thus, both answers which were posted for this question:

[How to remove/change the vertical spacing before and after an \algorithm environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25828/how-to-remove-change-the-vertical-spacing-before-and-after-an-algorithm-environ)

do not work.

How to fix this?

Comment: You should provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764) that illustrates your problem. That's the best way for community members to assess your situation and provide solutions.

Comment: I took the liberty to format your post a little. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [`layouts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/layouts) [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf) (section **6.2 Detailed float layout**, p 25) describes the possible lengths influencing the vertical space between floats and text body elements:

- `\textfloatsep` - between `t`op and `b`ottom-aligned float and text body (default is `20\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@`); and
- `\intextsep` - between float and text for other floats (default is `12\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 2\p@`).

The defaults for these are set in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx). Both these lengths have glue (meaning they can stretch/shrink). Here's a graphic from `layouts` showing the lengths involved.

[image]

Here's an incidental view on a change in `\textfloatsep` from the default to `0pt` with an example from the [`algorithmicx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\end{algorithm}
\lipsum[3-6]
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0pt}% Remove \textfloatsep
\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Note the visible difference in the vertical space below algorithm.

Comment: The main issue of using \textfloatsep is that it will set for the entire documents. So, if you add a figure after this command, this separation you've set will also affect the figure. What OP wanted, is a command that only affects the current float (such as \vspace). One way would be using \textfloatsep to the desired value before the algorithm, and setting it to the default value right after the algorithm. But, how to do that?

Comment: @rkioji: `\newlength{\textfloatsepsave} \setlength{\textfloatsepsave}{\textfloatsep} \setlength{\textfloatsep}{0pt} ... \setlength{\textfloatsep}{\textfloatsepsave}`. My suggestion would be to leave such things until the end of your document processing. Then, if you have a single float that you want to adjust, issue the appropriate negative `\vspace` to correct that particular float's spacing.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach is to place the algorithm inside a figure. Once inside  a figure, you can adjust whitespace using `\vspace{-1cm}` (or similar), just as you would for other figures. One nice aspect of this approach is that it doesn't change the spacing around other figures.

---

Full example:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
\vspace{-5em}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
  \EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\vspace{-5em}
\end{figure}
```