# How can I reduce space after an Algorithm in a two column document?

Tags: spacing, two-column, algorithms

I'd like to decrease the space between an algorithm environment and the text beneath it in my document. Looking at similar questions ([How to remove/change the vertical spacing before and after an \algorithm environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25828/how-to-remove-change-the-vertical-spacing-before-and-after-an-algorithm-environ) and [vertical space after algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62720/vertical-space-after-algorithm)) I tried:

- Negative vspace
- Changing the textfloatsep (either for the entire document, or just before the algorithm environment)
- Changing the intextsep (seemed unlikely, since my algorithm is at the top of a page, but I tried it anyway)

None of those worked. Here is a MWE based on an answer to the second question:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm*}[t]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\end{algorithm*}
\lipsum[10-20]
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{0pt}% Remove \textfloatsep
\begin{algorithm*}[t]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\end{algorithm*}
\lipsum[20-30]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE of multicolumn algorithm environments with space beneath]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for twoculmn mode `\setlength{\dbltextfloatsep}{<length>}`. Its the separation command for spacing between a two-column float and the text area.

For further informations [The layouts package: User manual](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/layouts/layman.pdf) p.28.

Here with `0pt` `\setlength{\dbltextfloatsep}{0pt}` ... :

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\setlength{\dbltextfloatsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm*}[t]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\end{algorithm*}
\lipsum[10-20]
\begin{algorithm*}[t]
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of a and b}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}\Comment{We have the answer if r is 0}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Euclid’s algorithm}\label{euclid}
\end{algorithm*}
\lipsum[20-30]
\end{document}
```