# Vertical line between two algorithms

Tags: algorithms

I am trying to put two algorithms side-by-side with a vertical line between them. I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}    
        \begin{minipage}{5cm}
            \begin{algorithm}[H]
                \caption{My algorithm}\label{euclid0}

                \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
                    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
                    \While{$r\not=0$}
                    \State $a\gets b$
                    \State $b\gets r$
                    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
                    \EndWhile
                    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
                    \EndProcedure
                \end{algorithmic}
            \end{algorithm}
        \end{minipage}
        &
        \begin{minipage}{5cm}
            \begin{algorithm}[H]
                \caption{My algorithm}\label{euclid1}

                \begin{algorithmic}[1]
                    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
                    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
                    \While{$r\not=0$}
                    \State $a\gets b$
                    \State $b\gets r$
                    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
                    \EndWhile
                    \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is b}
                    \EndProcedure
                \end{algorithmic}
            \end{algorithm}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The problem is, the vertical line drawn is longer than the vertical space taken by the algorithms:

[image]

How to fix this (erase top part of the vertical line which is at the top of the algorithm heading?)

**Note:** I tried with `minipage` and `\vline`, but it also has the same problem.

Comment: In order to remove the white space above the caption that causes the vertical line to 'start too early', you can use `\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt} ` as described here: [How to remove/change the vertical spacing before and after an 'algorithm' environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25835/134144)