# Change line spacing in algorithm2e

Tags: line-spacing, algorithm2e

I'm using the `algorithm2e` package.

In one algorithm with several math formulae in consecutive lines I would like to increase line spacing.

I've already searched `algorithm2e`'s documentation but could not figure out how to change line spacing. Does anybody know?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I haven't found any `algorithm2e` command to do that.

But this can be easily achieved with the help of the [`setspace`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package.

You can simply add the line (adjust `1.35` to your needs)

```
\setstretch{1.35}
```

just after the `algorithm` environment has begun.

Example (notice the difference between the first and the second algorithm, algorithm code taken from `algorithm2e` documentation):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e,setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\setstretch{1.35}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\bigskip

\begin{algorithm}
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
initialization\;
\While{not at end of this document}{
read current\;
\eIf{understand}{
go to next section\;
current section becomes this one\;
}{
go back to the beginning of current section\;
}
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

If you want this behavior to apply globally to `algorithm` environments, add the following lines to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{\setstretch{1.35}}
```

instead of using every time `\setstretch{1.35}` inside the environments.

Also note that, if you don't want to use the `setspace` package, you can substitute `\setstretch{1.35}` with `\linespread{1.35}\selectfont`.

Comment: Are you sure about the `[H]` option? Without `setspace` you should get the same effect by `\linespread{1.35}\selectfont`

Comment: @egreg, 1) I've just copied it from the documentation..., 2) Yes, I'm sure about `[H]`: it forces the algorithm NOT to float, 3) you are right about `\linespread{1.35}\selectfont` but I always use `setspace` for these things....

Comment: Well, not allowing big floats to float is a guarantee for bad page breaks.

Comment: @egreg I didn't say that I suggest to use it.... Anyway, I'll change it in the answer.

Comment: `\linespread` or `\setstretch` only seem to work well when you want to *increase* the spacing. However, decreasing doesn't seem to work well. E.g. there is no difference between `\linespread{1.0}\selectfont` and `\linespread{0.001}\selectfont`.

Comment: @JorisKinable You might want to check out [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16063/249769) answer. `\begin{spacing}` worked for me when I wanted to *decrease* the spacing.