# algorithm2e and extra vertical spaces

Tags: spacing, algorithm2e

### Solution

The comment below of David Carlisle gives the solution.

### Problem

With the code below, I can add extra vertical spaces **where I want but not everywhere**. My problem is that the compilation complains by saying the following ugly things even if at the end the job ii done. How can I do to make back peace between me and my LaTeX compiler ?

### Hurting log messages ;-)

```
./extra_vertical_space.tex:9: LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9     \\

?
```

### MMWE (Minimal Merly Working Example)

```
\documentclass[a4,11pt]{article}
    \usepackage[french, vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \KwData{some datas}
    \vspace{0.4em}
    \\
    \Begin{
        \vspace{0.4em}
        \\
        Step 1
        \\
        Step 2
        \\
        \vspace{0.4em}
        \\
        \While{one condition is true}{
            \vspace{0.4em}
            \\
            ... and so on.
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: never use `\\ ` at the beginning or end of a paragraph ` `\vspace{0.4em}\\ ` will always give the error you state, if you want a bigger space just give a bigger space eg `\vspace{1.5\baselineskip`

Comment: That does the job !

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `setspace` package to increase the linespacing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{doublespace}
    \KwData{some datas}
    \Begin{
      Step 1\;
      Step 2\;
      \While{one condition is true}{
        ... and so on.\;
      }
    }
  \end{doublespace}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question to indicate that the spacing are changed in some places and not every where. Your code remains useful.