# how to change the type of vertical line in algorithm environment while minimizing the vertical spacing

Tags: spacing, algorithm2e

I am trying to have a straight vertical line after `if` and `for` statements to remove the redundant space in algorithm environment.

I use `informs3` class that can be found in [this website](https://pubsonline.informs.org/authorportal/latex-style-files) where you should click `INFORMS Journal on Computing Style Files`.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[ijoc,nonblindrev]{informs3} 
\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII % current default line spacing
\TheoremsNumberedThrough     
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\For{$i \in V$} {
    \For{} {
        \If{}{
            \uIf{}{
                 $statement$
             }\Else{
                $statement$
             }
        }
    }
}
\Return{x}
\caption{{\sc My Algorithm}}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, I'd like to remove the spaces between the lines. None of the recommendations presented in this post [Vertical spacing in the algorithm environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16059/vertical-spacing-in-the-algorithm-environment) works.I would appreciate if someone could help me out.

Comment: Could you provide a compilable code reproducing the output? I compiled your code by placing it in an ``informs3`` class document loading the package ``algorithm2e``, but I got a different output.

Comment: I updated the post and here how it looks https://imgur.com/JME7YCh

Comment: @Vincent I solved the first issue.

Comment: @whitepanda: You want to reduce the *vertical* or *horizontal* spacing between the lines?

Comment: I want the minimize the vertical spacing. When I used ```lines```, the spacing increased even more.

Comment: For the vertical spaces between the ends of the vertical lines,  `\SetVlineSkip{0pt}` in combination with `vlined` might help.

Comment: I tried it, but did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the combination of the options `lined` and `noend`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[ijoc,nonblindrev]{informs3} 
\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII % current default line spacing
\TheoremsNumberedThrough     
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,lined, noend]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\For{$i \in V$} {
    \For{} {
        \If{}{
            \uIf{}{
                 $statement$
             }\Else{
                $statement$
             }
        }
    }
}
\Return{x}
\caption{{\sc My Algorithm}}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Or with `vlined` and `\SetVlineSkip{0pt}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[ijoc,nonblindrev]{informs3} 
\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII % current default line spacing
\TheoremsNumberedThrough   
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\For{$i \in V$} {
    \For{} {
        \If{}{
            \uIf{}{
                 $statement$
             }\Else{
                $statement$
             }
        }
    }
}
\Return{x}
\caption{{\sc My Algorithm}}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

---

The vertical spacing between the rows of the algorithm is quite large, since you used `\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII` in the preamble. To locally decrease the linespacing in the algorithm, you can use `\SingleSpacedXII` inside of the `algorithm` environment as shown in teh following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[ijoc,nonblindrev]{informs3}
\OneAndAHalfSpacedXII % current default line spacing
\TheoremsNumberedThrough   
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,lined, noend]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\SingleSpacedXII
\DontPrintSemicolon
\For{$i \in V$} {
    \For{} {
        \If{}{
            \uIf{}{statement}\Else{
                $statement$
             }
        }
    }
}
\Return{x}
\caption{{\sc My Algorithm}}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In the user manual, this is how the algorithms look https://imgur.com/a/CB3KTgd. I want mine to look like the same. When I run your code, there is still a huge gap between the lines. Please check https://imgur.com/IrzoY0L to see the output.

Comment: @whitepanda: I have updated my answer accordingly. Hope this helps.